# Toggling a class if aria-expanded == true using coffeescript or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, coffeescript

What I'd like to do is add a class if `aria-expanded == true` and remove it when aria-expanded is false.

```
if $(".panel-heading .panel-title > a").attr("aria-expanded" == "true") 
    $(".panel-heading .panel-title > a").toggleClass('a_red')
```

Right now this doesn't seem to be working!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check for attribute values the way you are doing now. You're missing a pair of opening and closing brackets in the `if-statement`. It should be like this:

```
if ($(".panel-heading .panel-title > a").attr("aria-expanded") == "true") 
    $(".panel-heading .panel-title > a").toggleClass('a_red');
```

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass` has an optional second parameter `state`.

> [`.toggleClass( className, state )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state)
>
> **state**
>
> A Boolean (not just truthy/falsy) value to determine whether the class
>   should be added or removed.

so this would add and remove the class:-

```js
var el = $(".panel-heading .panel-title > a");
el.toggleClass('a_red', el.attr("aria-expanded") == "true");
```

Comment: I'm using collapsible accordions, could you please help me out with a snippet, the accordion panel that is expanded needs to be highlighted in red.

Comment: @Jeevan update your question with a working example of what you have so far.